Editing using EditMessageMedia with list InputMediaPhoto JavaTelegram
I need to edit a message sent by my bot with one photo to a list of photos
I use the library https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api
I need to modify a message sent by my bot(The message contains a photo and text)
I usually do it as follows and everything works:
EditMessageMedia editMessageMedia = new EditMessageMedia(chatId, messageID,
                    new InputMediaPhoto(new File("images" + File.separator + "money.png")));
            this.bot.execute(editMessageMedia);

            EditMessageCaption editMessageText = new EditMessageCaption(chatId, messageID).caption(Main.getDictionary(languageCode)
                            .get("invoice"))
                    .parseMode(ParseMode.Markdown)
                    .replyMarkup(inlineKeyboardMarkup);

However now I need to change to a list of photos but EditMessageCaption accepts only one InputMedia object, I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!
My code:
File[] filesList = new File("images" + File.separator + "treasures" + File.separator + treasure.getId()).listFiles();
        List<InputMediaPhoto> inl = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File file : filesList)
            if (file.isFile())
                inl.add(new InputMediaPhoto(file));

        EditMessageMedia editMessageMedia = new EditMessageMedia(invoice.getChatId(), invoice.getMessageId(), inl);

        this.bot.execute(editMessageMedia);

        EditMessageCaption editMessageText = new EditMessageCaption(invoice.getChatId(), invoice.getMessageId())
                .caption("*" + treasure.getX() + " " + treasure.getY() + "*\n" +
                        "_" + treasure.getDescription() + "_")
                .parseMode(ParseMode.Markdown);
        this.bot.execute(editMessageText);


You can go through filesList one by one and send each photo using SendPhoto. Just make sure to include the chat ID and the file (InputFile) for each photo. This way, you can handle each photo individually and tweak captions or other details using the API as you need to.
...
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.request.SendPhoto;
...
for (File file : filesList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            // Send each photo individually
            SendPhoto sendPhoto = new SendPhoto(invoice.chat().id(), new InputFile(file));
            sendPhoto.caption(generateCaption(treasure)); 
            bot.execute(sendPhoto);

            updatePhotoCaption(invoice, file, treasure);
        }
    }

